# Why is my $_get not setting the variable to anthing?

Tags: php

I am working on a site and I am passing a variable through a url but my $_get isn't picking up the variable.
Here is an example link : http://www.testbench.x10.mx/?voucher=4df97e819f8dc2aa62557410d2c40ce9&ticketid=7006133

and here is my code using $_get

```
$code = ($_get["ticketid"]);
```

Can someone explain what I did wrong, or if I didn't do something wrong just tell me that something else in the code must be interfering.Thank you, Thomas

Comment: well you must write it in Capital Letters
but if problem is something else then try $_REQUEST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

user `$_GET` instead of `$_get`

Comment: Oh, Ok I didn't realize type mattered in PHP. That change fixed it.

Comment: @Tom Case is the issue here, not type.

Comment: Oh, wow I really need to get my names down. I'm still relatively new to programming. I have picked up PHP, without actually using any real reference materials, from my C# background, but I'm still a beginner there too.

Answer (score 0):

use it this way:

```
$code = $_GET['ticketid'];
```

that way the php software will understand what you doing?